# C# - Printing files regardles of type to printer

Tags: c#, shell, printing, process

currently I am working with application that should **silently** print files **regardless of their type** to **specific printer**.

I have method to print:

```
public static void SendToPrinter(string filePath, string fileName, string printerName)
{
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
        info.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Verb = "PrintTo";
        Process.Start(info);

 }
```

and this works almost perfect. 
I do not know how to force the printer to **leave the original image size**.
Currently the image is **scaled to the page size**.

Have you met someone with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell only sends print command to printer. There is no printer settings available. Instead try to use Print document. It has various printer settings.